# The hopf bundle over $S^1$ is a trivial bundle.

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles

The hopf bundle over $S^1$ is the bundle obtained after two twists. I was wondering if this bundle is the trivial bundle. Intuitively it seems like it should not be trivial since there are two twists but it seems like there exists a non zero section. So I do not know what is going wrong. If anyone can help it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What is the Hopf bundle over $S^1$?

Comment: @Michael AlbaneseFor mobius bundle we need to twist it once for hopf band we need two twists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hopf bundle is a one dimensional vector bundle and so since has a section, as you noted, it is automatically trivial. What is perhaps confusing is that the picture we normally think of is its embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$. This embedding is not isotopic to the normal embedding of $S^1 \times [0,1]$. To see this, note that the boundary of the hopf bundle is the hopf link wheras the boundary of the ordinary embedding of  $S^1 \times [0,1]$ is the unlink. Nevertheless, as abstract topological spaces they are diffeomorphic.

Comment: So can we not identify the number of twists using differential topology?

Comment: We can identify the number of twists of a particular embedding, but this is a property of the embedding, as opposed to a property of the bundle itself. However, we can only embed $S^1 \times [0,1]$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ with an even number of twists due to orientability considerations.

Comment: The first sentence in your answer is misleading: every non-trivial  vector bundle has  sections, even non-identically zero ones! Of course, I know what you mean but you should write formally correct statements :-) Also,  the Hopf bundle can be embedded in 3-space: each popular science book for laymen shows how you do that with a long thin piece of paper!

Comment: By the way, I find your videos on YouTube extremely pedagogical and your choice of material excellent.